# Remove folder contained in different folders

Tags: wildcard, windows-scripting

I solved a similar issue thanks to other user, but not works for folder.
I have these folders:
C:\Users\ge-15\documents\private
C:\Users\te-98\documents\private
C:\Users\ma-98\documents\private
C:\Users\ge-12\documents\private
C:\Users\vr-88\documents\private

I need to delete all the files and folders contained in private folders but only for the users that the name starts with GE (so in this case only for the users ge-15 and ge-12) I can't find any solution...

Thanks to all can help me.
Regards

The following command works for file (del command) but I cannot find any solution for the folders.
`for /D %%I in ("C:\Users\ge*") do del /A /F /Q  "%%I\documents\private\*" 2>nul`
For the folders I tried this:
`for /D /R %%I in ("C:\Users\ge*") do rmdir /S /Q  "%%I\documents\private\*" 2>nul`
without luck...

Comment: `powershell -Command "Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Users\ge*\documents\private\*' -Recurse -Force"` ? (I don't use Windows, so just guessing)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about PowerShell (sorry I'm working on linux in general)... I confirm that this command works launched from the shell! As script doesn't work, I'm trying to understand how...

Comment: for other users whit the same problems, in other forum suggest to me this batch script that works: @echo off
for /d %%i in ("C:\Users\ge*") do (
    del /a /f /q  "%%i\documents\private\*"
    for /d %%j in ("%%i\documents\private\*") do (
        rd /s /q "%%j"
    )
)